# sending nested data via json string POST to webapi c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, webapi

Im having an issue passing a nested list from my app to a web api. Im not seeing anything in my logs, but I keep receiving the following response in Postman:

```
{
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
"status": 400,
"traceId": "00-7d20c10b0a8b389f3ab9b13253d89356-96635c33db3d6d02-00",
"errors": {
    "$": [
        "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."
    ],
    "RawJson": [
        "The RawJson field is required."
    ]
}
```

}

When I input this JSON string in to the body/raw data with type set as JSON:

```
{
"RawJson": {
    "ParkSys_ID": 3,
    "Route_ID": 1,
    "TrailName": "test",
    "GPXData": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2022-10-07T13:38:19.877+00:00",
            "Latitude": 41.5263926,
            "Longitude": -81.6508186,
            "Altitude": 153.39999389648438,
            "Accuracy": 20,
            "VerticalAccuracy": 1.5861159563064575,
            "Speed": null,
            "Course": null,
            "IsFromMockProvider": false,
            "AltitudeReferenceSystem": 2
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2022-10-07T13:38:21.379+00:00",
            "Latitude": 41.5263905,
            "Longitude": -81.6508169,
            "Altitude": 153.39999389648438,
            "Accuracy": 13.423999786376953,
            "VerticalAccuracy": 1.2535593509674072,
            "Speed": null,
            "Course": null,
            "IsFromMockProvider": false,
            "AltitudeReferenceSystem": 2
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2022-10-07T13:38:22.921+00:00",
            "Latitude": 41.5263924,
            "Longitude": -81.6508156,
            "Altitude": 153.39999389648438,
            "Accuracy": 13.423999786376953,
            "VerticalAccuracy": 1.3553755283355713,
            "Speed": null,
            "Course": null,
            "IsFromMockProvider": false,
            "AltitudeReferenceSystem": 2
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2022-10-07T13:38:24.479+00:00",
            "Latitude": 41.5263905,
            "Longitude": -81.6508186,
            "Altitude": 153.39999389648438,
            "Accuracy": 13.538000106811523,
            "VerticalAccuracy": 1.3423168659210205,
            "Speed": null,
            "Course": null,
            "IsFromMockProvider": false,
            "AltitudeReferenceSystem": 2
        },
        {
            "Timestamp": "2022-10-07T13:38:25.992+00:00",
            "Latitude": 41.5263919,
            "Longitude": -81.6508162,
            "Altitude": 153.39999389648438,
            "Accuracy": 14.10200023651123,
            "VerticalAccuracy": 1.526308298110962,
            "Speed": null,
            "Course": null,
            "IsFromMockProvider": false,
            "AltitudeReferenceSystem": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

}

This is my class that should be handling this, and I'm not sure why its not seeing the RawJson nested in the json

```
public class ActivitySubmissionService : IActivitySubmission
{
    [JsonProperty("ParkSys_ID")]
    public int ParkSys_ID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Route_ID")]
    public int Route_ID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("TrailName")]
    public string TrailName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("GPXData")]
    public object GPXData { get; set; }

    private readonly GPSAPIContext gpsapiContext;
    public ActivitySubmissionService(GPSAPIContext gpsapiContext)
    {
        this.gpsapiContext = gpsapiContext;
    }

    //
    // this is sent JSON string
    public async Task<object> SubmitNewActivity(string RawJsonString)
    {
        var StringConvert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ActivitySubmissionService>>(RawJsonString);
        int Park_ID = StringConvert.Select(x => x.ParkSys_ID).FirstOrDefault();
        int Route_ID = StringConvert.Select(x => x.Route_ID).FirstOrDefault();
        string Trail_Name = StringConvert.Select(x => x.TrailName).FirstOrDefault();
        object GPXData = StringConvert.Select(x => x.GPXData).ToList();

        return GPXData;
    }
}
```

Comment: if the problem is in posting data to an API, then you need to post the relevant code.  The only code you have posted shows how you **deserialize** the data, not how you are serializing and posting it

Comment: At this junction Im taking the serialized json and submitting it via postman so I can see better whats going on. The code I submitted is whats relevant and the json is whats being sent to it via postman

Comment: if you are just posting the JSON using Postman and it still fails, there is not anything we can do to help you without knowing what the expected JSON payload is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I labored over this for a while...and it ended up being at least one obscure thing, followed by a mistake on my part.

I did not have

```
<Nullable>disable</Nullable>
```

Setup in my csproj file, which was causing the error

```
 "RawJson": [
    "The RawJson field is required."
]
```

Also, the way I was passing the `[FromBody]` data to my `SubmitNewActivity(string RawJsonString) {}` was completely wrong. I needed to pass it within my wrapper (which I hadn't even considered), and the nested element in my JSON was also requiring a wrapper class.

Another issue, which kind of totally threw me off, was that when passing the `[FormBody]`data to your method, if you pass it via your wrapper, it will automatically deserialize the data. So this error:

```
"$": [
    "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."
],
```

Was a byproduct of

```
var StringConvert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ActivitySubmissionService>>(RawJsonString);
```

Ultimately, the following code is what I ended up with:

```
 public class GPXDataWrapper
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
    public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
    public decimal Altitude { get; set; }
    public decimal Accuracy { get; set; }
    public decimal VerticalAccuracy { get; set; }
    public string Speed { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
    public bool IsFromMockProvider { get; set; }
    public decimal AltitudeReferenceSystem { get; set; }
}
public class ActivitySubmissionWrapper
{
    [JsonProperty("ParkSys_ID")]
    public int ParkSys_ID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Route_ID")]
    public int Route_ID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("TrailName")]
    public string TrailName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("GPXData")]
    public List<GPXDataWrapper> GPXData { get; set; } = new List<GPXDataWrapper>();
}

public async Task<string> SubmitNewActivity(ActivitySubmissionWrapper RawJsonString)
    {
        int Park_ID = RawJsonString.ParkSys_ID;
        int Route_ID = RawJsonString.Route_ID;
        string Trail_Name = RawJsonString.TrailName;
        List<GPXDataWrapper> GPXData = RawJsonString.GPXData;
        decimal Trail_Lat = GPXData[0].Latitude;
        decimal Trail_Lon = GPXData[0].Longitude;
        
        //
        // start the insert by creating the trailhead
        GPXTrailHead TrailHead_Insert = new GPXTrailHead();
        TrailHead_Insert.TrailHead_Name = Trail_Name;
        TrailHead_Insert.TrailHead_Lat = Trail_Lat;
        TrailHead_Insert.TrailHead_Lon = Trail_Lon;
        gpsapiContext.TrailHead.Add(TrailHead_Insert);
        return "test: " + Park_ID+" , "+Route_ID+" ,"+Trail_Name+" , "+GPXData;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so ASP.net does not support the `text/plain` content type.  The workaround would be to read the body ourselves.  For this to work, the action method must not declare any parameters.

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessJsonString()
    {
        using StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Request.Body, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        string body = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        // Now you can do whatever you need with the string, like parsing to JSON, although it is a weird approach.
        return Ok(GetMyDataFromTheString(body));
    }
```

Comment: So I've added that. When I build it I still get the JSON response that I originally posted. Its like Im missing something ,or adding more than whats necessary?

Comment: First of all, your question was not about how to appropriately receive your desired response, it was about resolving the HTTP 400 BAD REQUEST response you had when trying to send the data.  I believe I fixed that with my answer.  If you agree, please mark the answer as such.

Comment: Second, we will be happy to help you out with your next problem, but do so in a separate question.

Comment: The question was why am I receiving the response Im receiving from Postman when the JSON is correct with the code I supplied.

Comment: ASP.net caught me by surprise on this one.  Replaced the previous answer with a working version.  I tested this with Postman using text/plain.